# How to have links open in Google Chrome from emails?

Tags: iphone, google-chrome, mobile-safari, web-browser

Before switching to the Chrome browser app from mobile Safari when I would click a link in a email it would automatically open the page in Safari. Now clicking a link does nothing and I have to copy and paste it into Chome. How to have it open like before but in Chrome instead of Safari?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this on iOS. Maybe a future iOS will let you select your default browser but iOS, as of version 5, does not.